# EF4.3 create one to one or zero relationship failed

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I use EF4.3 to create 1 to 1...0 relationship, but it throw an exception of

> "The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_id'
>   already exists on table 'TestAs'"

The code as below

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (myContext context = new myContext())
            {
                TestA tA = new TestA();
                TestB tB = new TestB();
                TestC tC = new TestC();
                context.testA.Add(tA);
                context.testB.Add(tB);
                context.testC.Add(tC);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    class TestA
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        //public TestB NavB { get; set; }
        //public TestC NavC { get; set; }
    }

    class TestB
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public TestA NavA { get; set; }
    }

    class TestC
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public TestA NavA { get; set; }
    }

    class myContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestA> testA { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TestB> testB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TestC> testC { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestC>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Which entity is the principle in here?

Comment: Hi Eranga, TestB and TestC are the principle entities

Comment: Then `TestA` can not be mapped with shared primary key. The model is not valid(practical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `WithRequired` in your `OnModelCreating` method by `WithOptionalPrincipal`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithOptionalPrincipal();
  modelBuilder.Entity<TestC>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithOptionalPrincipal();
}
```

(If A would be the principal entity you'd use `WithOptionalDependent`.)

**EDIT**

After your comments I think it would be interesting to see the effect of adding two classes TestD and TestE, giving A two navigation properties TestD and TestE and do this in your model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestB>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithOptionalPrincipal();
modelBuilder.Entity<TestC>().HasOptional(x => x.NavA).WithOptionalPrincipal();
modelBuilder.Entity<TestA>().HasRequired(x => x.NavD);
modelBuilder.Entity<TestA>().HasRequired(x => x.NavE);
```

Table A now has four foreign keys: to B and C (nullable), to D and E (not nullable). I think the latter is what you want.

Comment: Hi GertArnold, the code seems modify my relationship. If I have only TestA and TestB in my code, everything works well, but after adding the TestC into the code, the "index has already exists in the table TestA" exception was thrown. Any idea?

Comment: Please look at my initial post, if there's no TestC class in the code, only TestA and TestB, comment the "modelBuilder.Entity<TestC>().HasOptional(x=>x.NavA).WithOptionalPrinciple();", the code works, but if the code is like the initial post, it can't work

Comment: Your code (using the 2 lines WithOptionalPrincipal) works well here. Did you change anything else?

Comment: but with 'WithOptionalPrincipal', it modify the relationship as 0..1 to 0..1, not 1 to 0..1

Comment: 1 to 0..1 That is B (1) to A (0..1)?

Comment: So basically you require B and C to exist when there is an A. But your class model expresses that A can exist without both. Then you should have NavB and NavC in A as you commented out.