# The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_AuctionId' already exists on table 'Bids'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662969/the-operation-failed-because-an-index-or-statistics-with-name-ix-id-already-ex%20-%20which%20was%20never%20really%20answered.%20I%20have%20a%20more%20real%20world%20example%20here.) which was never answered. I have a more real world example here though - so hoping for some help.

I have an auction, bid and auctiondetail(a flattened table) class.
I am trying to include my bids in the auction as well as auctiondetail table, auction and auctiondetail have the same PK

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace OnCall.VirtualWarehouse.Data.Models.Auctions
{
    using System;

    public class AuctionCopy
    {
        public Guid AuctionCopyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Collection<BidCopy> BidCopies { get; set; }

    }

    public class BidCopy
    {
        public Guid BidCopyId { get; set; }

        public Guid AuctionCopyId { get; set; }

        public AuctionCopy AuctionCopy { get; set; }


    }

    public class AuctionDetailCopy
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid AuctionCopyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Collection<BidCopy> BidCopies { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Here's my DBContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    static DataContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateIfChangeInitializer());
    }

    public DataContext()
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public IDbSet<AuctionCopy> AuctionCopy { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<BidCopy> BidCopy { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<AuctionDetailCopy> AuctionDetailCopy { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }

    public void Seed(DataContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

When generating the database, I get

```
    The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_AuctionId' already exists on table 'Bids'.
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Does marking the "Key" property [NotMapped] not solve the problem?  Why do you need the additional property "Key" overridden?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried completely removing the key property as it didn't really have anything to do with the problem. Updated the question above to reflect this change. The problem persisted even with the key property removed.

Comment: Did you refresh the schema in the database after doing that?  Try pushing the schema into an empty database.

Comment: Yeah, did that already. It's when trying to regenerate a new database I'm getting the error above.

Comment: Please paste your fluent init code as well.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the index that gets created on BidCopy is the same name due to the naming of the key on AuctionCopy and AuctionDetailCopy. Is there any way of overriding that?

Comment: When I change the key on AuctionDetailCopy from AuctionCopyId to AuctionDetailCopyId, it works. Not ideal for my purposes, so question still remains - is there a way of making the above code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug come from EF4.3 (and 4.3.1).
It should be fixed for the next release.

Have a look on [Unhandled Exception after Upgrading to Entity Framework 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441924/unhandled-exception-after-upgrading-to-entity-framework-4-3-1). They purpose a workaround using migration system.